# Hellish amouth of syntax errors

Tags: c

Im trying to create a small game in C and SDL to get started with SDL in a fun way. Ill paste inn my Timer struct and function that will be used to cap the fps in my main game loop. BUT i get a lot of "error C2054: expected '(' to follow 't'", about 25 errors in total.

Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "SDL.h"

struct Timer {

    int startTicks;
    int pausedTicks;

    int paused;
    int started;

};

void Init( Timer *t )
{
    t->startTicks = 0;
    t->pausedTicks = 0;
    t->paused = 0;
    t->started = 0;
}

void StartTimer( Timer *t )
{
    t->started = 1;
    t->paused = 0;

    t->startTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
}

void StopTimer( Timer *t )
{
    t->started = 0;

    t->paused = 0;
}

void PauseTimer( Timer *t )
{
    if( t->started == 1 && t->paused == 0 )
    {
        t->paused = 1;
        t->pausedTicks = SDL_GetTicks() - t->startTicks;
    }
}

void UnpauseTimer( Timer *t )
{
    if( t->paused == 1 )
    {
        t->paused = 0;
        t->startTicks = SDL_GetTicks() - t->pausedTicks;

        t->pausedTicks = 0;
    }
}

int GetTicks( Timer *t )
{
    if( t->started == 1 )
    {
        return t->pausedTicks;
    }
    else
    {
        return SDL_GetTicks() - t->startTicks;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whats wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the included files found?

Comment: Please read the error message carefully - on which line is the "error C2054"? I would start searching for the error there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those `t` variables should be of type `struct Timer` rather than `Timer`.

Or, alternatively, define it as:

```
typedef struct sTimer {
    int startTicks;
    int pausedTicks;
    int paused;
    int started;
} Timer;
```

to make `Timer` a "first-class" type.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you either need to do this:

```
struct Foo
{
    ...
};

...

void bar(struct Foo *p);
           ^
```

or this:

```
typedef struct Foo
{  ^
    ...
} Foo;
   ^
...

void bar(Foo *p);
```

[I prefer the second version; it saves having to write `struct` all over the place.]

Answer (score 1):

Find the first error and work from it. Often, many of the others are consequences of the first one.

Comment: s/Usually the/Often, many of the/